Combinatorial Species and Associated Categories of Given Structures
A combinatorial species is a pre-sheaf of sets on the groupoid of finite sets. For instance, the combinatorial species $U: {\bf fSet^\simeq} \to {\bf Set}$ sends a finite set $X$ to the finite set $U(X)$ of the hypergraphs on $X$ closed under unions.
At this point, I can consider various types of categories of hypergraphs closed under unions. I can suppose that the objects are of the form $(X,\mathcal{A})$, where $X$ is a finite ground set and $\mathcal{A}$ is any hypergraph on $X$ closed under unions. Concerning the morphisms, I have various choices: for instance, if $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ I can possibly consider:

the functions $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(A) \in \mathcal{B}$ for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$;

the functions $f: X \to Y$ such that $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $B \in \mathcal{B}$.


Based on the previous example, I have some general questions:

In the theory of combinatorial species, it seems that there is no way to use the machinery of the theory in order to define a collection of categories as those I previously defined. Why? (if otherwise there is, can you give me a detailed explanation of how to get them)

This is so strange, because when studying and introducing a combinatorial species, one may ask for a category of a certain kind. For instance, given the combinatorial species of union-closed hypergraphs, one expects to define at least one category of union-closed hypergraphs. In terms of objects, there is no problem, as you can see in the example. The problem is actually related to the choice of morphisms. And this is my second question below:

Is there a formal criterion to define all possible categories whose objects are structures of a given combinatorial species? Namely, in the example of union-closed hypergraphs, is there the possibility of using some machinery from the theory in such a way to construct all possible categories of union-closed hypergraphs (or at least part of them)?

Please, it is possible to get a point-by-point answer?
